# Access the views inside a relative layout using UIautomator

Tags: android

I am trying to automate the GFX benchmark.
Where i want user to have the option select the test.
But when using the UIAutomator i am not able to find the exact resID to access a particular text..

[image: GFX]

As you can see the `Test selection`  . i need to click that but i am not able to do so.

i tried the following code and few variants
`new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(TextView.class.getName()).textContains("Test")).click();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I was not able to click that particular UI element but i devised a workaround for this.
Basically i just clicked that area based on pixels.Took a screenshot and calculated the percentage positioning of the element and just clicked it.
The code was this

```
UiDevice device = getUiDevice();        
int height = device.getDisplayHeight();
int width = device.getDisplayWidth();
device.click((int)(width*0.75), (int)(height*.625));
```

Hope this helps anyone stuck on similar issue.Also, if any one has better solution please let me know. :)